Как прочитать "будущий" файл из пакета npm?
Я создал пакет npm, который должен прочитать конфигурационный файл, создаваемый пользователем в корневой папке проекта, куда этот пакет будет установлен. Как настроить этот пакет, чтобы после установки он мог прочитать этот файл, которого изначально не существует.
Я даже пробовал сделать так:
import { dbconfig } from "../../../dbconfig.ts";

Это относительный путь, чтобы прочитать файл dbconfig.ts из папки node_modules. Но этот способ выдает ошибку и проект не может быть собран, так как основан на typescript (а также файла dbconfig.ts изначально не существует в пакете npm). Есть ли способ решения этой проблемы и как это сделать?

Проблема решена с помощью: const { dbconfig } = require(${process.cwd()}/dbconfig.ts); Хотя не знаю, является ли это наилучшим решением.
